# How to keep count between specific times between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to keep track of how many meals a person has given from two dates you can enter from DateTimePickers.

There are three meals a day between specific times between:

- 6-8AM Meal 1
- 12-2PM Meal 2
- 5-7PM Meal 3

If a person arrives after one of the specific times, they miss out on a meal, so for example if I arrive on 1 Jan 2018 3AM and leave on 2 Jan 2018 2PM I will only receive 5 meals, as I missed out on the last meal.

This is the code I have come up with, but unfortunately I struggle to work the code out if the time between the two dates are more than one day apart.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimeExit.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        dateTimeArrive.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        DateTime timeArrived = dateTimeArrive.Value;
        DateTime timeExit = dateTimeExit.Value;

        int totalHoursArrived = timeArrived.Hour;
        int totalHoursExit = timeExit.Hour;
        int totalCounts = 0;
        int countA = 0; //6-8 AM
        int countB = 0; //12-2PM
        int countC = 0; //5-7PM
        int totalDaysLeft = (timeExit - timeArrived).Days; //determines the number of days between the two given dates.

        if (totalDaysLeft == 1)
        {
            totalCounts = 3;
            countA = 1;
            countB = 1;
            countC = 1;
        }
        else if (totalDaysLeft < 1) //difference between the two dates is less than a day.
        {
            totalCounts = totalDaysLeft * 3;
            countA = totalDaysLeft;
            countB = totalDaysLeft;
            countC = totalDaysLeft;

            if (timeExit.Day == timeArrived.Day) //if the dates are on the same day and "less than one day"
            {
                if (totalHoursArrived <= 8 && totalHoursExit >= 17) //if date is before or on 8AM and leaves on or after 5PM.
                {
                    countA = 1;
                    countB = 1;
                    countC = 1;
                }
                else if (totalHoursArrived <= 8 && (totalHoursExit >= 12 && totalHoursExit < 17)) //if date is before or on 8AM and leaves before 5PM
                {
                    countA = 1;
                    countB = 1;
                }
                else if (totalHoursArrived <= 8 && totalHoursExit < 12) //if date is before or on 8AM and leaves before 12PM
                {
                    countA = 1;
                }
                else if ((totalHoursArrived <= 12 && totalHoursArrived > 8) && totalHoursExit >= 17) //if date is before or on 12PM and leaves on or after 5PM
                {
                    countB = 1;
                    countC = 1;
                }
                else if ((totalHoursArrived <= 12 && totalHoursArrived > 8) && totalHoursExit < 17) //if date is before or on 12PM and leaves before 5PM
                {
                    countB = 1;
                }
                else if (totalHoursArrived >= 17) //if date is after or on 5PM
                {
                    countC = 1;
                }
                totalCounts = countA + countB + countC;
            }
            else //less than a day, but not on same day exit time.
            {
                if (totalHoursArrived <= 8) //if date is before or on 8AM.
                {
                    totalCounts = 3;
                    countA = 1;
                    countB = 1;
                    countC = 1;
                }
                else if (totalHoursArrived >= 12 && totalHoursArrived < 17)// //if date is after or on 12PM and arrival time is less than 5PM
                {
                    totalCounts = 2;
                    countB = 1;
                    countC = 1;
                }
                else if (totalHoursArrived >= 17) //if date is after or on 5PM
                {
                    totalCounts = 1;
                    countC = 1;
                }
                if (totalHoursExit > 0) // exit time
                {
                    if (totalHoursExit >= 17)
                    {
                        totalCounts += 3;
                        countA += 1;
                        countB += 1;
                        countC += 1;
                    }
                    else if (totalHoursExit >= 12 && totalHoursExit < 17)
                    {
                        totalCounts += 2;
                        countA += 1;
                        countB += 1;
                    }
                    else if (totalHoursExit >= 6 && totalHoursExit < 12)
                    {
                        totalCounts += 1;
                        countA += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else //more than two days difference between the two dates.
        {
            **//the part I am struggling to figure out**
        }

        lblTotalCountA.Text = "Count A: " + countA;
        lblTotalCountB.Text = "Count B: " + countB;
        lblTotalCountC.Text = "Count C: " + countC;
        lblTotalAmount.Text = "Total Counts: " + totalCounts;
    }
```

Comment: Find the biggest number of 24-hour spans that your date interval contains (`(int)TotalHours / 24`). Add that number * 3 to the answer. Subtract that number * 24 hours from the original timespan. Now you are left with a timespan that is less than 24 hours, which you already know how to handle. Handle it and add its result to the previous `3*X`.

Comment: @GSerg I am a bit confused on how I should find the biggest number of 24-hours, can you perhaps provide me with an example?

Comment: [`(int)TotalHours / 24`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063957/how-to-keep-count-between-specific-times-between-two-dates?noredirect=1#comment94961050_54063957)

Comment: @GSerg What I meant was if you could perhaps give it in a example you would use it, because I tried to do it like you said but if I substract "the number * 24 " from the timespan (TimeExit - TimeArrived) I can't determine then what counter to count as it only returns the number of hours remaining.

Comment: Yes, it returns the number of hours remaining. These remaining hours start at `TimeArrived`. You effectively replace `TimeExit` with `TimeArrived + (TimeExit - TimeArrived).AddHours(-X*24)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code quite difficult to mantain (if you would like to add a fourth meal in the future, it would be a nightmare to change your code), so I'm giving you a different approach, as well as answering your question.

First I would define a class like this:

```
public class DayMeals
{
   private int[] entryTimes = new int[] { 6, 12, 17 };
   private int[] exitTimes = new int[] { 8, 14, 19 };
   private int[] mealCounts = new int[3];
   private bool countHalfMeals = false;

   public DayMeals(bool countHalfMeals)
   {
       this.countHalfMeals = countHalfMeals;
   }

   public void AddFullDay()
   {
       mealCounts[0]++;
       mealCounts[1]++;
       mealCounts[2]++;
   }

   public void CountMealsForADay(DateTime timeArrived, DateTime timeExit)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < mealCounts.Length; i++)
       {
           int mealEntryTime = entryTimes[i];
           int mealExitTime = exitTimes[i];
           if (timeArrived.Hour <= mealEntryTime && timeExit.Hour >= mealExitTime)
               mealCounts[i]++;
           else if (countHalfMeals && timeExit.Hour > mealEntryTime && timeExit.Hour <= mealExitTime)
               mealCounts[i]++;
       }
   }

   public void PrintMealsCount()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < mealCounts.Length; i++)
       {
           System.Console.WriteLine($"Meal #{i + 1} count = {mealCounts[i]}");
       }
   }
}
```

Then, I would simply instantiate the class and call the functions:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
   CalculateMeals(new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 15, 12, 1), new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 18, 0, 0));
}

public static void CalculateMeals(DateTime timeArrived, DateTime timeExit)
{
   // Number of full days
   int fullDaysNumber = (timeExit - timeArrived).Days;
   DayMeals dayMeals = new DayMeals(true);
   for (int i = 0; i <= fullDaysNumber; i++)
   {
       int hoursDiff = (int)(timeExit - timeArrived).TotalHours;
       if (timeExit.Day > timeArrived.Day && hoursDiff > 24)
       {
           dayMeals.AddFullDay();
           // A trick to make the cycle work the next time
           // You can use a different variable if you want to keep timeArrived unchanged
           timeArrived = timeArrived.AddDays(1);
       }
       else if (timeExit.Day < timeArrived.Day)
       {
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           if (timeArrived.Day != timeExit.Day)
           {
               dayMeals.CountMealsForADay(timeArrived, new DateTime(1,1,timeArrived.Day,23,59,59));
               dayMeals.CountMealsForADay(new DateTime(1,1,timeExit.Day,0,0,1), timeExit);
           }
           else
           {
               dayMeals.CountMealsForADay(timeArrived, timeExit);
           }    
       }
   }

   dayMeals.PrintMealsCount();
}
```

I tried this code and it seems to work as expected. Please review it and let me know if this is what you wanted to achieve.

NOTE: I know the usage of "AddDays(1)" is counterintuitive, because I am keeping the same hour of day 1 for a subsequent day. But, if you are not interested about the fact that a person entered at 11 on Monday rather than on Tuesday, the meals count is the same. Basically, I'm just traslating the entry time to the last day.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code Fabio, however I seem to encounter a problem where as if the arrival time is for example 7AM, it doesn't register the first meal. It seems that I cannot choose a date where the hour is greater than the given entryTimes

Comment: You are right, but @Aldert accepted answer does not really work either. Try his code with these dates and it won't count the third meal at January 1st:

DateTime timeArrived = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 15, 3, 1);
DateTime timeExit = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 7, 34, 1);

By the way, I have changed my code to make it work properly in all situations. You can enable the "countHalfMeals" bool variable if you want to count a meal as "done" even if the exit time is in between the meal time... 

Please let me know.

Comment: Fabio, you are correct at the time I accepted Aldert's answer as the solution I realised it didn't work and forgot to unaccept the answer. I have tested your newly changed code and it seems to work perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, without looping. I simplified further by only using standard c# objects. The trick is in counting full days and work with timespans.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime timeArrived = new DateTime(2019, 1, 5, 13, 53, 0);
            DateTime timeExit = new DateTime(2019, 1, 6, 8, 46, 0);

            TimeSpan startMeal1 = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan endMeal1 = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan startMeal2 = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan endMeal2 = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan startMeal3 = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan endMeal3 = new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0);


            int daysDiff = (timeExit - timeArrived).Days;

            int meals1Count = daysDiff;
            int meals2Count = daysDiff;
            int meals3Count = daysDiff;

            TimeSpan timeDiff = timeExit - timeArrived - TimeSpan.FromDays(daysDiff);

            if (timeArrived.TimeOfDay <= endMeal1 && (timeArrived.TimeOfDay + timeDiff) >= startMeal1) meals1Count++;
            if (timeArrived.TimeOfDay <= endMeal2 && (timeArrived.TimeOfDay + timeDiff) >= startMeal2) meals2Count++;
            if (timeArrived.TimeOfDay <= endMeal3 && (timeArrived.TimeOfDay + timeDiff) >= startMeal3) meals3Count++;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Aldert, this code works perfectly appreciate it.

Comment: After spending more time testing the code it seems it fails to count the meals properly for dates like 5-Jan-2019 1:53PM and 6-Jan-2019 8:46AM. I do however appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I havent checked this in VS but something like this should work. I copied your same day code, assuming its correct also:

```
public class MealCalculation
    {
        int countA, countB, countC = 0;
        int total = 0;
        public void Calculate()
        {

            var start = DateTime.Now;
            var finish = DateTime.Now;

            // Same Day
            if (start.Date == finish.Date)
            {
                MealsCalculate(start.Hour, start.Hour);
            }
            // Next Day
            else if (start.AddDays(1).Date == finish.Date)
            {
                MealsCalculate(start.Hour, 24);
                MealsCalculate(0, finish.Hour);
            }
            // Great Than 1 Day
            else
            {
                // First Day
                MealsCalculate(start.Hour, 24);

                // Middle Full Days
                var days = NumberOfDays(start.Date, finish.Date);
                countA += days;
                countB += days;
                countC += days;

                // Finish Day
                MealsCalculate(0, finish.Hour);
            }

            // Total
            total = countA + countB + countC;

        }
        public int NumberOfDays(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
        {
            var days = 0;
            while (start < finish)
            {
                start.AddDays(1);
                days++;
            }
            return days - 1;
        }


        public void MealsCalculate(int totalHoursArrived, int totalHoursExit)
        {
            if (totalHoursArrived <= 8 && totalHoursExit >= 17) //if date is before or on 8AM and leaves on or after 5PM.
            {
                countA += 1;
                countB += 1;
                countC += 1;
            }
            else if (totalHoursArrived <= 8 && (totalHoursExit >= 12 && totalHoursExit < 17)) //if date is before or on 8AM and leaves before 5PM
            {
                countA += 1;
                countB += 1;
            }
            else if (totalHoursArrived <= 8 && totalHoursExit < 12) //if date is before or on 8AM and leaves before 12PM
            {
                countA += 1;
            }
            else if ((totalHoursArrived <= 12 && totalHoursArrived > 8) && totalHoursExit >= 17) //if date is before or on 12PM and leaves on or after 5PM
            {
                countB += 1;
                countC += 1;
            }
            else if ((totalHoursArrived <= 12 && totalHoursArrived > 8) && totalHoursExit < 17) //if date is before or on 12PM and leaves before 5PM
            {
                countB += 1;
            }
            else if (totalHoursArrived >= 17) //if date is after or on 5PM
            {
                countC += 1;
            }
        }

    }
```